# what is the meaning of sat in algebraic equation?

Tags: functions, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

What's the meaning of sat() in downside equation :

```
                                  f(x,y)=sat(x-y)
```

regards,

Comment: Where your problem is coming from? Maybe $z$ at saturation? Saturated solution, saturated transistors in electronics, saturated colors are only a few example coming to my mind...

Comment: I want to know what s the meaning of f(x,y)=sat(x-y) for example ,

Comment: Still, what is "downside equation" to see where your function is coming from?

Comment: I cannot fathom how your question relates to the tags, if you know why it is linked to special functions, please enlighten us.

Comment: @Bacon right, this is the first time I see a question containing both special-functions and regular-expressions tags :)

Comment: Generally it referred to nonlinear systems where I see this function in an example and I dont know what is it or where is come from ,

Comment: If you are talking about "nonlinear control systems", sat() is the unit saturation function.But if you are just talking about "nonlinear systems" in general, I don't know. you should put the right tags and explanation in the question, so people know what are you talking about.

Comment: I think it is unit saturation function but would you tell me what is it ?!

Comment: Let me emphasise the question by @Momo: **Where your problem is coming from?** Did a hand appear floating in the air, which wrote the equation on a wall in your living room? Or maybe you've found it in some handbook or some web page...? The title of the book or URL of the page would be very helpful to those who would like to answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Momo above - I believe you are talking about the unit saturation function in that:
$$\text{sat}(x-y) = \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if} \quad x>1+y \\
      x-y, & \text{if} \quad |x-y| \leq 1 \\
      -1, & \text{if} \quad  x-y < -1
    \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks, that's right I thing,